# Dynamically add arguments in if condition in python

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I am writing code for a tick-tac-toe game that uses grids. I am trying to check the condition where all the cells of a row match with each other, so that players can be declared winners. Also, I am using dynamic sizes of board (3 by 3, 4 by 4, 5 by 5....). So for this purpose, I am using if condition in a for loop. The problem is that I can't figure out a way to add arguments dynamically to the if statement. The if defined is static and I can't add the condition of the last cell of the row (if size increases from 3 by 3 to 4 by 4).

expected outcome:

3 by 3 grid:

```
count = 0
for i in range(dim):
    if grid[count]=="X" and grid[1+ count]=="X" and grid[2+ count]=="X":
       count1 = 0
       print ("Player X win")
       print ("-------------")
       for i in range(dim):
           print(grid[0 + count1 : dim + count1])
           count1 =+ dim
       print ("-------------")
       count += dim
```

I am trying to loop for all rows to check the match.

What I want is to change the `if grid[count]=="X" and grid[1+ count]=="X" and grid[2+ count]=="X":` to incorporate the change of the grid size from

3 by 3 to

4 by 4

```
if grid[count]=="X" and grid[1+ count]=="X" and grid[2+ count]=="X" and grid[3+ count]=="X":
```

5 by 5

```
if grid[count]=="X" and grid[1+ count]=="X" and grid[2+ count]=="X" and grid[3+ count]=="X" and grid[4+ count]=="X":
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Use a second loop to check for X's, counting hiw many you find (or breaking out of the loop when you find a not-X)

Comment: You can use `all()` to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all()` with a generator expression for this:

```
 if all(grid[count + i] == "X" for i in range(dim)):
```

There's also a corresponding `any()` for `or` conditions

---

There are three pieces to how this works:

- Comprehensions; we can write a list like `[grid[count + i] == "X" for i in range(dim)]` which will evaluate to something like `[True, True, False, True]`; it's basically a short-hand for a `for` loop that produces a list (or a dict or a set, if we use `{}`).
- The `all()` (or `any()`) function; this is a simple function that takes a list and returns whether all (any) are true; `all([True, True, False, True])` is `False`
- Generator expressions; generators are basically single-use lists where the values are calculated only as they're needed. The syntax for a generator expression is either omitting the `[]`, as here; or using round brackets `()`, where the syntax would otherwise be too confusing.

  Because the values are calculated only as needed, this can be very valuable if we don't want to (or can't) store all the values in memory at once, or if we're likely to only look at the first few values. The `all()` function does that - it only checks as far as needed for the result to become clear. That's not much of an advantage when there's only going to be 3-5 values with a simple calculation, of course; here, it's mostly that it looks neater without the `[]`.

  One downside of generators is that they don't print well; you have to convert them to list to print out the items, and then you've used them up and can't use them again in the calculation. For debugging, the `[grid[count + i] == "X" for i in range(dim)]` form is more convenient.

Comment: Although `all` is obviously the preferred way to do this, I think a good answer would first present how to do this with a simple for-loop, then show how using `all` makes it even cleaner. Otherwise it looks a bit like `all` is doing some black magic. Example of a for-loop: `all_Xs = True; for i in range(dim): all_Xs = all_Xs and grid[count+i] == 'X';  if all_Xs: ...`

Comment: I guess I should at least show the pieces with a list comprehension, shouldn't I; I'll add something when I'm at my keyboard

Comment: okay, I tried this and it works perfectly with all(). But how about if have to do the same for checking all the cells in column match (and want to do this iteratively in a for loop to cover all columns in a grid)?

Comment: I got it.   if all(grid[count + i] == "X" for i in range(0, (dim * dim), dim)):   and count += 1

Comment: how do I do this for diagonal elements in a grid?

Comment: @Stef - reply expanded to add explanation

Comment: @Sazee - very similar, you just need to work out the correct offset for each item on the diagonal

Comment: @JiříBaum I tried but was not able to get how to check diagonals dynamically. Can you help?

Comment: You'll need to put together a formula for the offset of those cells; try writing them out by hand for the 3x3, 4x4 and 5x5 cases and see what the pattern is?